# Unrecognized key-values

Tags: documentclass-writing, key-value, kvoptions

I try to implement a personnal class using key-value options (I am a beginner in that field).
For exemple, I would like to specify the language (for babel package) with an option "langue=xxx" with "francais" as default value. I tried the *kvoptions* package as follows :

Class file : (I give you the whole list of packages in case you detect a conflict)

```
\ProvidesClass{mepp}[2014/03/08 Personnal class development version]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareStringOption[francais]{langue}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*


\LoadClass[twoside]{report}


\RequirePackage[paper=a4paper, lmargin=15mm, rmargin=15mm, tmargin=15mm, bmargin=15mm,
                    includeall, marginparwidth=44mm, headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{emerald}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{array, multirow, tabularx}
\RequirePackage{xcolor, color, colortbl}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, mathrsfs, stmaryrd, gensymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx, picins}
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage[top]{mcaption}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\RequirePackage[fit]{truncate}
\RequirePackage[upright]{fourier}
\RequirePackage{mdwlist}
\RequirePackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage[globalcitecopy]{bibunits}
\RequirePackage{multido}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{marginfix}

\RequirePackage[geometry]{ifsym}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage[strict]{changepage}
\RequirePackage{framed}


\PassOptionsToPackage{\mepp@langue}{babel}
```

Tex file :

```
\documentclass[langue=francais]{mepp}
...
```

but compilation fails : compiler says there is no language specified for babel.
If I do not specify any option or if I give a "wrong" option without "=" symbol, compilation works, because it assigns the default value to "langue".

So, why is the option "langue=francais" not recognized ? Thanks for your help.

(sorry for language, I am French)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have `\PassOptionsToPackage{\mepp@langue}{babel}` after `\RequirePackage{babel}` which is a possible source of your problem. Try `\RequirePackage{\mepp@langue}{babel}` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're loading `babel` before `\PassOptionsToPackage{\mepp@langue}{babel}` so the option is not evaluated; just use

```
\RequirePackage[\mepp@language]{babel}
```

If you want to load `babel` only if the `langue` option is specified, you can do

```
\DeclareStringOption{langue}
```

and then

```
\ifx\mepp@langue\@empty\else
  \RequirePackage[\mepp@langue]{babel}
\fi
```

so if the `langue=...` option is not specified, `babel` won't be loaded.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! But I do not understand : if I do not specify the option "langue", \mepp@langue takes the defaut value "francais" and option is correctly evaluated although babel is loaded before the command \PassOptionToPackage... Why ?

Comment: @EmmanuelG. With the syntax you use, `\mepp@langue` is initialized to `francais`.